# Conversion failed when converting the varchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm getting the conversion error in SQL. I have tried Casting and Convert as int but failed.

```
SELECT 
    ProdId, ParentCat, ProdFullName, ProdImage 
FROM 
    Product
WHERE
    ProdId IN (SELECT Compared FROM Product WHERE ProdId = 10803)
```

- `ProdId` is `int`
- `Compared` column is `varchar`

`Compared` column values are :

```
32879, 10844, 10747, 81113, 8001, 81469
```

Comment: A *single* string containing multiple digits and commas is not at all the same thing as *multiple* integers. Do a search for splitting a string on commas in SQL if you want to persist with this non-relational approach, or instead, split this data out into *multiple* rows which each contain a single value in an appropriate `int` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you should build the query as a string and execute it

`DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @query = 'SELECT 
    ProdId, ParentCat, ProdFullName, ProdImage 
FROM 
    Product
WHERE
    ProdId IN (' + Compared + ')' FROM Product WHERE ProdId = 10803 
EXEC (@query)`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    ProdId, ParentCat, ProdFullName, ProdImage 
FROM 
    Product
WHERE
    ProdId IN (SELECT convert(int,ltrim(rtrim(Compared))) 
              FROM Product WHERE ProdId = 10803)
```

Read more about [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In that case you just cast ProdId as a varchar.

```
WHERE
CAST(ProdId AS varchar(10)) IN (SELECT Compared FROM Product WHERE ProdId = 10803)
```